# Add fadeOut to current JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
            var tab = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
            $(tab).fadeIn(1200);

        });
    });
```

This is for tabbed menu with contents (using jQuery, of course).

When I opening new tab, current contents fades out wery fast, but new tab contents opens slowly (as indicated 1200).

So, how can I edit this existing script to fade out contents slowly?

Example http://jsfiddle.net/2uts2kdt/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2uts2kdt/9/

Check out the updated JSFiddle above. Basically you want to call the fadeIn once the fadeOut is complete. You need use `promise().done()` because the fadeOut is called on multiple elements. So once it is all done it will call the done code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).fadeOut(1200).promise().done(function() {
            $(tab).fadeIn(1200);
        });        
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Does JQuery's promise work with addClass/removeClass as well ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you want to add a `fadeOut` call instead of just setting it to `display:none`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).fadeOut(1200);
    $(tab).fadeIn(1200);

});
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but.. there are another problems then :)

Comment: @MihaelsJeksons What other problems?

Comment: New tab contents is displayed below (i can't it explain), but when fadding ends, he jumps up :)

Comment: @MihaelsJeksons Add your markup to the question so I can see what the HTML looks like.